# Cyclic dependencies on multi-module maven project with AspectJ and Lombok

Tags: maven, aspectj, cyclic

I am working with a third-party application, whose code is available, and I am trying to use AspectJ to get some additional behavior on a particular module (lets say A module) of such application. The application has more modules (lets suppose B and C modules), but I only need to apply extra functionality on the A module.

I have created an AspectJ module. I am using Maven as a build tool. I have the following project structure:

```
project 
+-- aspect-module 
|   | 
|   +- pom.xml 
| 
+-- A module 
|   | 
|   +- pom.xml 
| 
+-- B module 
|   | 
|   +- pom.xml 
| 
+-- C module 
|   | 
|   +- pom.xml 
| 
+ pom.xml
```

The point is that the aspect-module defines an aspect which depends on the A module code (imports several of its tracked classes). For this reason, it does require a compile time dependency on the A module, thus, the aspect-module/pom.xml includes the A module dependency.

The pom.xml files I have are the followings.

Aspect module pom

```xml
...
<parent>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>aspectModule</artifactId>
<properties>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     ...
</dependencies>
```

A module pom.xml

```xml
...
<parent>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>AspectModule</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Bmodule</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <mainClass>Main</mainClass>      
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration> 
                   <mainClass>Main</mainClass> 
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>AspectModule</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main pom.xml

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>project</groupId>
<artifactId>main</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>AModule</module>
    <module>BModule</module>
    <module>CModule</module>
    <module>AspectModule</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>AspectModule</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>AModule</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<properties>
    ...
</properties>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo> -->
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <!-- IMPORTANT -->
          <phase>process-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
          <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
          <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>a-make-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I need to include the aspect module dependency in the module A pom.xml since, otherwise, I get the error: *The artifact project:aspectModule referenced in aspectj plugin as an aspect library, is not found the project dependencies*

I did mvn clean install in the main project but as the result maven refuses to compile projects saying that they contain cyclic references.
Can anyone help me?

thank you!

Comment: You cannot have cyclic dependencies. You may need to either split A into two modules or merge A and the aspect-module.

Comment: Bea, I would appreciate some feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*J Fabian Meier* is right, you cannot have cyclic references in a Maven project. (What was first, the chicken or the egg?)

Let me elaborate a bit on his brief two suggestions and add a third one FYI:

Your choices are as follows:

1. Because `aspectModule` seems to be clearly targeted at `moduleA`, even using A's classes, simply put the aspects into A.
2. In other uses cases, you might want `aspectModule` to be re-usable by other modules or projects. Then you could, as J. Fabian said, split off a `common` module of `moduleA`. Both `aspectModule` and `moduleA` could then depend on `common`, and `moduleA` could depend on `aspectModule` without any circularities.
3. You could also remove the `aspectModule` dependency from `moduleA` and keep it unwoven. Then you could add `wovenModuleA`, depending on `aspectModule` and `moduleA` and do the weaving there. All other modules would, if they need aspect-enhanced A-type functionality, depend on `wovenModuleA`, not on the unwoven version. But that option only makes sense if you do not have the source code for `moduleA`, need to do binary weaving and load-time weaving is not an option.

Technically, all 3 options are viable. Which one makes most sense, depends on your scenario. The way you described it, the first and simplest one looks like a good choice.